# Microsoft Graph Beta SDK Search throws exception "The call failed, please try again." 0x713DBA9F

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to search with app-only credentials and the MS Graph Beta SDK.

The search query works fine in the graph explorer. I've copied the C# code snippet from there:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var requests = new List<SearchRequestObject>()
{
    new SearchRequestObject
    {
        EntityTypes = new List<EntityType>()
        {
            EntityType.DriveItem
        },
        Query = new SearchQuery
        {
            Query_string = new SearchQueryString
            {
                Query = "test"
            }
        },
        From = 0,
        Size = 25
    }
};

await graphClient.Search
    .Query(requests)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

However the request returns an exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: 0x713DBA9F Message:   The
> call failed, please try again.  Inner error:  AdditionalData:     date:
> 2020-07-01T10:13:47   request-id: db08906e-2b78-4a57-8109-dcbc6b306c2e
> ClientRequestId: db08906e-2b78-4a57-8109-dcbc6b306c2e

It should not be a permission error, as I fixed one exception about permission by adding Files.Read.All to the App in AD and giving consent to the tenant.

How can I find out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found this which seems to show [/beta/search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) is not supported for application token, but needs delegate token.

I'll try to use  [/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) instead which should support application tokens.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7727